# Updating the Project to .Net Framework 4 and building it doesnot work on windows server 2003

Tags: asp.net, dll, .net-4.0, asp.net-3.5

We updated the project from 3.5 to dot net framework 4.0 ,build and deploy it on windows server 2003,the default page was loaded but when we access any other pages it shows error:
 404 File Not Found
The page that you are looking for might have been removed,had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. 
Again when I build the same project on the server the error goes off and the pages redirects as usual.But when I build on My Machine which has windows 7 and upload the dll ,the same problem occurs.Is there any thing to do with the dll with windows.
What could be the problem of this.We are tired searching of the solution.We would be grateful you provide us the actual cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problems occur for os change. It does't support in Windows 7